# Makefile executes wrong command

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am using the following makefile for my project:

```
IDIR    =       -I/a/include
INSURE  =
CC      =       gcc
CEFLAGS =       -fverbose-asm -masm=intel
AFLAGS  =
LFLAGS  =
WFLAGS  =       -Wall -Wextra
LDIR    =       -L/a/lib.Linux
LIBS    =       -lpthread -lpopt
OLVL    =       -O3

b.exe: b.o c.o
    $(CC) $(DBG) -o $@ $^ $(WFLAGS) $(IDIR) $(LDIR) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.s
    $(CC) -c $(DBG) $< $(AFLAGS) $(WFLAGS)

%.s: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -S $(DBG) $< $(OLVL) $(CEFLAGS) $(IDIR) $(WFLAGS)

.PHONY: debug
debug:
    $(eval DBG=-g)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.s
```

Based on this I am expecting to generate an assmebly file as the first step.  However when I run this, I get

```
$make b.exe 
gcc    -c -o b.o b.c
```

It appears to me that make is skipping my rule for making b.o, and is instead running a default rule.  I am wondering why and how do I fix it?

I am using GNU Make 3.80 and gcc 3.4.6.

Comment: It must be that your .s and .o files are up-to-date, is that right?

Comment: Have you disabled all built-in rules? `make` probably has one for `%.o: %.c`

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin No.  I thought that might be the problem, so I ran the `clean` rule to force them to be remade, and I got the same output.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau That worked!  I added `-r` on the command line.  But I still don't understand why this is happening.  I thought make was supposed to pull rules from the make file before using the built-in rules.

Comment: @Degustaf: Rules in the makefile overrule default rules for the same pattern, but I don't believe that is the case for a sequence of 2 (or more) rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules you define in your makefile *do* take precedence over the built-in rules, but "one step" rules (which can directly produce an output from an existing input) trump "multi-step" chains of rules (which produce an output from an existing input by way of an intermediate file), even if the multi-step chain is user-defined and the one step rule is built-in.

In your case, you've defined a chain of pattern rules:

```
bar.c -> bar.s -> bar.o
```

But this is longer than the built-in rule to create `bar.o` from `bar.c`:

```
bar.c -> bar.o
```

In fact, the implementation of GNU make is such that multi-step chains of rules are not even considered until after all of the one-step pattern rules have been checked.  Of course, since there is a one-step rule that matches in your example, GNU make uses that and never bothers looking at multi-step chains.

As you've found, you can workaround this by using `-r` on the command-line to disable *all* the built-in rules.  You could also add an override to your makefile for the specific built-in rule that is causing you trouble.  Literally that would look like this:

```
%.o: %.c
```

That is, just redefine the built-in rule with no commands.